# How do you target an element with a specific class when handling an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to JQuery and still learning...

The below script swaps the class of a div when the image is clicked. How do I isolate the images so that only an image with the class of .thumbnail triggers the script?

```js
< script >

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").click(function(e) {
      var newclass = $(this).attr("class");
      var oldclass = $("#fullsize").attr('class');
      $("#fullsize").removeClass(oldclass).addClass(newclass);
    })
  }); 

< /script>
```

Comment: $('img.thumbnail').click(function(e) {$('#fullsize').attr('class',$(this).attr('id'));});

Comment: So the 'click' thing is outdated, not to mention none of the answers deal with [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Not saying that the answers are wrong, just suggesting a more modern approach.

Comment: $('body').on('click','img.thumbnail',function(e) {$('#fullsize').attr('class',$(this).attr('id'));});

Answer (score 1):

```
$("img.thumbnail ").click(function(e) { // add the class along with the img selector
  var newclass = $(this).attr("id");
  var oldclass = $("#fullsize").attr('class');
  $("#fullsize").removeClass(oldclass).addClass(newclass);
})
```

[This link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) may help you to understand different selectors in jQuery

Answer (score 1):

`$('img')` will select all the img in you document.

`$('img.thumbnail')` will select all the img in your document that have `thumbnail` class.

You can combine `removeClass` `addClass` operation by just replacing the class attribute.

```
$('img.thumbnail').click(function(e) {
    var newclass = $(this).attr('id');
    var oldclass = $('#fullsize').attr('class');
    $('#fullsize').attr('class',newClass); // Note: No need to removeClass and then addClass. Simply Replace the value of class attribute.
});
```

Comment: do we any more need this line var oldclass = $('#fullsize').attr('class');

Comment: I'm not sure. From the look of it, we may not need it for it is declared as a `var`. however, what if we want to revert the changes back to original? In that case we may need to retain the older values. (I understand, in this code, it is not possible. It can be made possible by moving the `var oldclass` declaration outside.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {       
   $("img.thumbnail").click(function(e) {           
     var newclass = $(this).attr("id");               
     var oldclass = $("#fullsize").attr('class');  
     $("#fullsize").removeClass(oldclass).addClass(newclass);  
   });                  
});
</script>
```

Comment: if there is a **div with class** `.thumbnail` it will trigger the event OP wants `img` only

Comment: this will find the child of `img with class .thumbnail`

Comment: `img .thumbnail` will give you all the elements `inside` img tag that have class thumbnail. The correct way is `img.thmbnail` img tags that also have class thumbnail. Please note, there is no space between img and .thumbnail. :)